# Warning: #1411 Incorrect datetime value: '1/1/2019 9:52 AM' for function str_to_date

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to fetch all data between two dates in MySQL. . I have use the following code to do it workable:

```
SELECT * FROM checkinout WHERE PIN = 214 
 AND (STR_TO_DATE(CHECKTIME, '%n/%j/%Y %h:%i %l') 
 between '1/1/2019 12:00:01 AM' and '1/1/2019 11:59:59 PM') 
 ORDER BY checkId ASC
```

My `CHECKTIME` table is varchar and My date format is: `Month/Day/Year Hour:Minute A/PM`. But when I run this, it returns a error like this:

```
Warning: #1411 Incorrect datetime value: '1/1/2019 9:52 AM' for function str_to_date
```

I have searched in web for 3 hours. But nothing help me.
Can you please tell me where I need to change?
Thanks.

Comment: Do not store dates in a char column. Store it as a date

Comment: Actually I have import it from a attendance machine. So if I use `DATE` , all data is save as `000000000000`.

Comment: What should `%n` be? `%j` is day of year, think you should use `%e` instead.

Comment: n - A numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros (1 to 12)

Comment: How have you imported it?

Comment: It is `%m` as i can see here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp

Comment: I have a SQL file that contain all the sql command like this:```INSERT INTO checkinout
  (PIN,CHECKTIME,verifycode)
VALUES('5','1/30/2019 8:02 PM','FP');```

Comment: You should have spent 3 minutes RT?M https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment above correctly says, you should avoid storing your dates in your MySQL table as text.  Please use proper date columns instead.  Now, getting to your two problems, first, you are parsing your date strings incorrectly using `STR_TO_DATE`.  You should be using the following mask:

```
%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p
```

Here is your updated query:

```
SELECT *
FROM checkinout
WHERE
    PIN = 214 AND
    STR_TO_DATE(CHECKTIME, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p') BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:01' AND
        '2019-01-01 23:59:59'
ORDER BY checkId;
```

In addition to fixing your timestamp mask, note also that I am using valid MySQL date/timestamp literals in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I guess it should be `%m/%d/%Y` or `%c/%e/%Y`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel You might be right, the timestamp is not clear beacuse the day and month happen to be the same.

Comment: It's not clear from the question. But OP is using `%n/%j/%Y` and believes (see comments) `n` stands for month.

Comment: Yes n stand for month. My date format is: `Month/Day/Year Hour:Minute A/PM`

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, I have also try your exact code. But same error was happened.

Comment: Try using the mask `%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p`

Comment: Woh, Thanks Tim Biegeleisen. I just need to change here `BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:01' AND '2019-01-01 23:59:59`. By the way, The closing bracket `)` is not necessary. Otherwise it will produce an error. thanks.

Comment: Please change your table design to not store dates as text.  You should view my answer as a temporary fix.